# Western Digital Caviar SE16 not recognized

Tags: hard-drive

Before I start, I have been looking at quite a few websites and I still have not found an answer to my problem. I have been building my own computer recently and I have just received the hard drive (WD Caviar SE16 WD5000AAKS) I was planning to put in my computer. After connecting the SATA power cable (99.99999% sure it is connected correctly) and the SATA cable to my motherboard (ASUS M5A78L-M/USB3) I booted my computer into a Linux Mint 13 XFCE 64-bit live USB expecting to see a hard drive when I came to install. Sadly when I checked the only hard drive that was showing was /dev/sda which was my USB with the Linux files on it. I also checked gparted and no hard drive other than my USB was showing up there either. Lastly I checked my BIOS and no matter what SATA port I connected the HDD to it wouldn't show up there either. Does anyone have any advice?

Some images of my set-up which could help are bellow:
[image: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/_DJGUyyncIy6p5ucpyKppNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink]

[image: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/7de--X52VRJJaND7jR_47tMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink]

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Hmm… Maybe just restore the BIOS settings to defaults, could possibly fix something…

Comment: Tried it, doesn't seem to work :-\

Comment: Can you describe the sound the disk makes when the machine is turned on?

Comment: There is no noise coming from the hard drive but it heats up quite a fair bit if you touch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the person I bought the HDD off sent me the wrong one (he had two identical and one was broken). He just swapped them and it works perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a little master/slave switch on the drive? It might be set the wrong way.

Also, in the BIOS, make sure your 'Data Mode' or similar is not on RAID.

Comment: Thanks again but that still does not work. Also there is no master/slave switch on the drive as it is SATA.

Comment: @NStorm Oh right, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

When power on the computer, can you hear any click sound from the hard disk? If that is the case, then the SATA power cable from the PSU can not provide enough power to the hard drive. You can try it on another PSU.

Comment: I don't hear anything from the HDD but the HDD does heat up quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another pc? Plug the drive in that one and if you have an OS installer, like a Windows 7 or Ubuntu disk, run the installer on the other pc, then wipe the drive and try again. I've had the same problem, although Western Digitals don't usually have it.

Comment: Sadly I don't have another SATA machine I'll be able to open to test in.

Comment: try using a sata converter in ide macheen if youdont have one them you can get one at newegg.com and there cheap